# Copying array in array of pointer to char

Tags: arrays, c, linux, segmentation-fault, char

I have an char array and I am trying to copy a part of it (tokenization) into 0th index of array of pointer to char using the strncpy function. But during runtime a segmentation fault occurs.

Code example:

```
char array[30] = "ls -l";
char* args[10];

strncpy(args[0], array + 0, 2);
```

Comment: You try copy only the first 2 characters without even putting a NUL terminator. Is this intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *args[10]` has the following declaration:

> declare args as array 10 of pointer to char

That is to say, we have an array of uninitialized pointers. We'll need to make those pointers point somewhere first, before trying to place characters there. Remembering that we must NUL terminate (`'\0'`) C strings, we can simultaneously allocate and NUL out space for our string by using [`calloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc).

This will make space for just `'l'`, `'s'`, and our mandatory `'\0'`.

```
char original_command[30] = "ls -l";
char *args[10] = { 0 };
args[0] = calloc(3, sizeof (char));
strncpy(args[0], original_command, 2);
```

Alternatively, we can use [`malloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc), but we must remember the NUL terminating byte.

```
args[0] = malloc(3);
strncpy(args[0], original_command, 2);
args[0][2] = '\0';
```

It's generally a good idea to always initialize our variables - see how we initialize our `args` array to be full of `NULL` pointers (`0`). Makes it very clear they don't point anywhere useful yet.

Also note that [`strncpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) does not place a NUL terminating byte if it was not found in the first `n` bytes of our source string. This is why it's very important to manually terminate our destination string.

Additionally, any call to an [`*alloc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) function must be matched later by a call to [`free`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free), when we are finished using that memory.

```
/* Do whatever needs to be done */
/* ... */
free(args[0]);
```

Comment: sizeof(char) is by definition 1

Comment: @0___________ Sure is. This, however, showcases exactly what the second argument to  `calloc` is.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate space for the copied string content; `char* args[10]` reserves only space for holding the pointer to the content, not for the content itself. And don't forget to reserve space for the string terminating character `'\0'` then.

```
args[0] = malloc(2+1);
strncpy(agrs[0],array+0,2+1);
agrs[0][2] = '\0';
```

Comment: It would also be a good idea to null terminate the string in `args[0]`.

Comment: `strncpy(agrs[0],array+0,2+1)` looks fishy anyway.

Comment: This has UB as `strncpy` will copy the first `3` bytes (being `'l'`, `'s'`, `' '`), and not NUL terminate properly.

Comment: Seems, people have problems writing `args`. Second time in this thread. ;-)